# How to integrate Spring boot with servlet 3.0 container and make it work in Websphere 8.5.5 server?

Tags: java, websphere-8, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have a working project developed with Spring boot, spring boot security and spring data rest with Maven.

As a standalone class working fine. WAR deployment in Tomcat also working fine. I have generated an EAR out of the WAR with Maven and deployed in WAS 8.5.5 is not working.

Standalone Java class which is woking fine with embedded Tomcat also with external Tomcat 7. Same failing to start with websphere not sure is any other configuration I am missing?

```
    package com.marsh.forms;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class FormsRestApplication2 extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(
                FormsRestApplication2.class, args);

    }   

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<FormsRestApplication2> applicationClass = FormsRestApplication2.class;

    @Bean
    // Magic entry
    public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
        DispatcherServlet ds = new DispatcherServlet();
        ds.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
        return ds;
    }

}
```

WAR pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.marsh</groupId>
        <artifactId>testparent1</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.marsh</groupId>
    <artifactId>testwar1</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                    <exclusion><groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId></exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        **<!-- <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId> 
            <scope>provided</scope> 
        </dependency> -->**

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <start-class>com.marsh.forms.FormsRestApplication2</start-class>        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>        
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
                            <plugin>
                     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                     <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Ignore-Scanning-Archives>spring-boot-starter-data-rest-1.3.0.M5.jar, hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar</Ignore-Scanning-Archives>  
                                <Ignore-Scanning-Packages>org.springframework.data.rest.core, org.hibernate,javax.persistence </Ignore-Scanning-Packages>
                            </manifestEntries>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                </plugin>

        </plugins>
        <finalName>testwar1</finalName>
    </build>
    <organization>
        <name>marsh</name>
        <url>www.marsh.com</url>
    </organization>
    <scm>
        <developerConnection>szdasd</developerConnection>
    </scm>
</project>
```

---

ear pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.marsh</groupId>
    <artifactId>testparent1</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>testear1</artifactId>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.marsh</groupId>
            <artifactId>testwar1</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skinnyWars>true</skinnyWars>
                    <defaultJavaBundleDir>lib</defaultJavaBundleDir>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>com.marsh</groupId>
                            <artifactId>testwar1</artifactId>
                            <contextRoot>/forms</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>

                    </modules>
                    <generateApplicationXml>true</generateApplicationXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
        <finalName>forms</finalName>

    </build>
</project>
```

parent pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.marsh</groupId>
    <artifactId>testparent1</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version> -->
        <version>1.3.0.M5</version>
        <relativePath>/</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.0.M5</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <modules>
        <!-- <module>testwar</module> <module>testear</module> -->
        <module>testwar1</module>
        <module>testear1</module>
    </modules>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
                <!-- <version>3.1</version> -->
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Ear generated successful and I can see proper update in application.xml about was project with context root. War also generated fine with classes and lib metaInf info.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Vendor: xxx
Implementation-Title: testwar1
Implementation-Version: 0.1
Implementation-Vendor-Id: com.marsh
Ignore-Scanning-Packages: org.springframework.data.rest.core, org.hibe
 rnate,javax.persistence
Built-By: abc
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_80
Ignore-Scanning-Archives: spring-boot-starter-data-rest-1.3.0.M5.jar, 
 hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.0.4
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

Couple of issues I noticed:

1. the issue is EAR deploying in server but not WAR and I don't see either spring boot starter or my classes getting loaded or publishing my spring rest data URLs:

   ```
   [11/5/15 18:24:46:088 EST] 00000070 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0200I: Starting application: testear1
   [11/5/15 18:24:46:088 EST] 00000070 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0204I: Application: testear1  Application build level: Unknown
   [11/5/15 18:24:48:260 EST] 00000070 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl WebGroup SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: Archetype Created Web Application.
   [11/5/15 18:24:48:397 EST] 00000070 WASSessionCor I SessionContextRegistry getSessionContext SESN0176I: Will create a new session context for application key default_host/forms
   [11/5/15 18:25:20:583 EST] 00000070 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [testear1#testwar1-0.1.war]:.No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
   [11/5/15 18:25:20:583 EST] 00000070 webcontainer  I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl addWebApplication SRVE0250I: Web Module Archetype Created Web Application has been bound to default_host[*:9081,*:80,*:9444,*:5063,*:5062,*:443].
   [11/5/15 18:25:20:640 EST] 00000070 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0221I: Application started: testear1
   [11/5/15 18:25:20:640 EST] 00000070 CompositionUn A   WSVR0191I: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=testear1 in BLA WebSphere:blaname=testear1 started.
   ```
2. This may be because of version mismatches but i am using jDK7 in all compiler, runtime and WAS 8.5.5 running in JDK7.

   ```
   [11/5/15 18:23:59:185 EST] 00000072 visitor       W com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.AnnotationInfoDefaultVisitor visitAnnotation [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.InfoVisitor@572832628 ] for method [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.info.impl.MethodInfoImpl@2048932859 ( org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource.collectionResourceDescription ) ] Name [ null ] Description [ Lorg/springframework/data/rest/core/annotation/Description; ] Call in violation of protocol
   [11/5/15 18:23:59:196 EST] 00000072 visitor       W com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.AnnotationInfoDefaultVisitor visitAnnotation [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.InfoVisitor@572832628 ] for method [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.info.impl.MethodInfoImpl@-535225858 ( org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource.itemResourceDescription ) ] Name [ null ] Description [ Lorg/springframework/data/rest/core/annotation/Description; ] Call in violation of protocol
   ```

I have used latest spring boot version for "@ControllerAdvice(basePackageClasses = RepositoryRestExceptionHandler.class)" class is required.

Answer (score 1):

Resolution: I could able to resolve this issue with servlet2.5 container meaning i have changed web.xml like below and followed below thread steps to make it work as i could not get quick solution to make it work with servlet 3.0 in WAS 5.5.5.0

https://bp3.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/210443048-Running-Spring-Boot-JPA-apps-in-WebSphere-8-5-5

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>com.marsh.forms.FormsRestApplication2</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

springSecurityFilterChain
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy

```
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

since i have changed the container version i have also lowered the hibernate and spring boot jpa version to execute my project.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    4.0.0
    
        com.marsh
        testparent1
        0.1
    
    com.marsh
    testwar1
    0.1
    war

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <!-- <exclusion>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            </exclusion> -->

                <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId></exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-legacy</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId> 
        <scope>provided</scope> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <start-class>com.marsh.forms.FormsRestApplication2</start-class>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>        
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                 <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Ignore-Scanning-Archives>spring-boot-starter-data-rest-1.3.0.M5.jar, hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar</Ignore-Scanning-Archives>  
                            <Ignore-Scanning-Packages>org.springframework.data.rest.core, org.hibernate,javax.persistence </Ignore-Scanning-Packages>
                        </manifestEntries>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
            </plugin>

    </plugins>
    <finalName>testwar1</finalName>
</build>

<scm>
    <developerConnection>abc</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

spring boot starter class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class FormsRestApplication2{ 


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(
                FormsRestApplication2.class, args);

    }

    private static Class<FormsRestApplication2> applicationClass = FormsRestApplication2.class;

    @Bean   
    public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
        DispatcherServlet ds = new DispatcherServlet();
        ds.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
        return ds;
    }

}
```